# Installation of nvim-go fails with "Undefined variable: g:go#debug"

Tags: go, vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm switching to neovim and try to get `nvim-go` running. My `Plug` section in my `init.vim` looks like this:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'zchee/nvim-go', { 'do': 'make'}
Plug 'sebdah/vim-delve'

call plug#end()
```

If I open `nvim` and run `PlugInstall`, I get the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing
/home/domma/.vim/plugged/nvim-go/plugin/nvim-go. vim: line   20:
E121: Undefined variable: g:go#debug
```

I checked the file and the error makes sense. But I have no idea where this variable comes from, how it should be set. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary edit the line in `/home/domma/.vim/plugged/nvim-go/plugin/nvim-go.vim: line 20`

`if g:go#debug` -> `if exists('g:go#debug')`